# PHP Wrap Javascript/JQUERY In Iteration Counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good morning all.  I have an issue I've been fighting for hours and can't seem to wrap my head around.  I am writing a page in PHP using JQUERY to dynamically add rows to a table.  I assigned a counter variable to keep elements separate for processing.  My code on the button (inside a PHP print statement):

```
<input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" id=\"newrow$i\" value=\"Add Exception\"/>
```

The JQUERY code (wrapped in PHP):

```
$x=$i;
for ($y = 1; $y <= $i; $y++) {
    $x++;
    if ($x % 2 == "0") {
        $class2 = "td1";
    } else {
        $class2 = "td2";
    }
    print "\$('#newrow$y').click(function() {\n";
    print "var CFNAME = \$('#cfname$y').val()\n";
    print "var CLNAME = \$('#clname$y').val()\n";
    print "var CID = \$('#rcid$y').val()\n";
    print "var PFNAME = \$('#pfname$y').val()\n";
    print "var PLNAME = \$('#plname$y').val()\n";
    print "var PID = \$('#pid$y').val()\n";
    print "var LANG = \$('#lang$y').val()\n";
    print "var YEAR = \$('#year$y').val()\n";
    print "var CURRICBUNDLE = \$('#curricbundle$y').val()\n";
    print "var BOOK = \$('#curricbookh$y').val()\n";
    print "\$('#curricreqexctable > tbody').append('<tr style=\"text-align: center;\"}><td class=\"$class2\">$x</td><td class=\"$class2\">' + CFNAME + ' ' + CLNAME + '</td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ecfid$y\" value=\"' + CID + '\"/><td class=\"$class2\">' + PFNAME + ' ' + PLNAME + '</td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"epid$y\" value=\"' + PID + '\"><td class=\"$class2\">' + LANG + '</td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"elang$y\" value=\"' + LANG + '\"><td class=\"$class2\">Year ' + YEAR + '</td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"eyear$y\" value=\"' + YEAR + '\"><td class=\"$class2\">' + CURRICBUNDLE + '</td><td class=\"$class2\">' + BOOK + '</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"7\"class=\"$class2\"><textarea style=\"width: 725px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid black; float: left;\" placeholder=\"Why Is Exception Being Requested?\" wrap=\"hard\" required=\"required\"></textarea></td></tr>');";
    print "});\n";
}
```

This code produces exactly what I want - with one exception.  When I click the button, a new row is added and the values come in properly.  However, the id (`$x`) seems to get stuck.  Suppose I click `Add Exception` for the first entry in a 3 row table.  The id shows up as `4`, as expected.  If I click it again (there could be more than one exception per row), it prints `4` again - I need it to increment to `5`.  I've tried wrapping it in another `for` loop, both inside and outside the existing loop, with no luck.  I've also tried moving the `$x` and the incrementer all over - but no luck.

I appreciate any help you can provide!!

Comment: You're incrementing on the server when you create the page, not on the client every time you add a row. You should be using a Javascript variable to increment on the client.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.  I tried that, but I couldn't get it to increment properly.  I declared: var z = "0" where the if-else is, then: x++ below the final print statement.  Any thoughts on where I went wrong?

Comment: You'll need to post your new code, it's hard to tell just from that description.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the responses.  Turns out, my question was irrelevant at the end.  Without the js iterations, it was doing what the customer wanted it to do.  :)